# Play only audio with VLC

Tags: command-line, vlc

Is there any way to launch VLC from the command line such that it will not play the video, only the audio, of an MP4 file?

Comment: See my new addition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can start `vlc` from the command line by:

```
vlc --vout none /path/to/file.mp4
```

So `vlc` uses no video output module and the video will not be played, only the audio.

See [chapter 2](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch02.html) of the user guide for all input and output modules of `vlc`.

You can bring `vlc` to nearly everything. I thought there was also a option to make me a sandwich.

Comment: Did I detect an XKCD reference? Nice one.

Answer (score 16):

Although `vlc --vout none /my/video.mp4` accomplishes **sound without video**, it still opens `vlc`'s GUI. Try this command to play only audio in your terminal:

```
cvlc --no-video /my/video.mp4
```

You can still express it in terms of a `vlc` video output module:

```
cvlc --vout none /my/video.mp4
```

To randomly play a directory of music right from the command line with:

```
cvlc --random /my/music/directory
```

Comment: Thanks,that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: the most interesting solution on Ask Ubuntu. thanks < 3

Answer (score 2):

## Use `--novideo`

To disable the video track you can simply do `--novideo`. This will stop it from playing.

### Alternatively

If you do `--vout none`, you'll likely have poor performance and you'll get scammed with

```
get_buffer() failed
thread_get_buffer() failed
decode_slice_header error
no frame!
```

But this will result in no video for the stream to be played with. This won't stop vlc from trying though.